# How to detect SmartBanner

Tags: ios, css, responsive-design

A smartbanner is apple's direct link to the app store.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

I am trying to have the smart banner show on the top of the page, content below it, and the nav bar on the bottom.  The issue I run into is the smart banner is not counted as part of screen height.  If you were to do either:

```
height: 100%;
screen.innerHeight;
height: 100vh;
```

or any other typical request for screen height, it ignores the presence of the smart banner and pushes content offscreen by the delta of the smart banner's height.

I am trying to detect if the smart banner is showing on an iOS device to ensure the page fits the window screen regardless of its presence and updates height accordingly.  What I've found is that the smart banner shows after the document is ready, and doesn't affect window height.  Is there a simple way to detect if the user is being shown the smart banner?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  heightResize($(".container"));

  $(window).resize(function() {
    heightResize($(".container"));
    $(".container").append("<div class='banner'>this is your dynamically created banner</div>");
    $(".container").height($(".container").height()+$(".banner").height());
  });
});

function heightResize(element) {
  element.height($(window).height()-20);
  $("p").text(element.height());
}
```

Code like this will be pushed off the screen by the smart banner after the page finishes loading.

Comment: They say the best way to ***detect if the smart banner is showing*** on a smartphone is, by far, watching the device closely for long periods of time. The longer the better. Without blinking, if possible. If you need help with your `code`, try creating a [mcve] of your problem. As in... post it.

Comment: I had a math professor say something similar, but in this situation I wasn't sure how a code sample could specifically help.  Stating I tried height: 100%; might prove I attempted the problem but wouldn't serve much more.

Comment: The problem here is terminology. `detect`, `smart banner`, `showing` are all terms that don't help much in understanding your specific need, so we could help out. Providing a working example might help. Another thing that would greatly improve understanding would be knowing the final goal. If your best friend came to you and told you exactly what you have told us, do you think you could help him? You'd have to ask for more information, which is exactly what I'm doing. Anyway, with the added info, your question slowly becomes understandable and answerable.

Comment: the issue for me is that I have a boss that asked me to make a mobile app that shows the full screen regardless of the smart banner being there so it feels like an app and responds to the smart banner but I can't seem to find support.  It would be nice if apple allowed jQuery to detect the smartbanner, but attempts at detecting the smart banner's presence in the html for the page didn't work either.

Comment: I can't find an example of a page that has done this either, so I'm not sure if it's something that's possible.

Comment: As you can see, no one answered. Not because people don't want to help, but because they don't understand what you ask. Why are you assuming we know what "the smart banner" is or that we know what your `HTML` markup looks like?

Comment: @Rob did you get a solution to this?

Comment: no, unfortunately not